# При работе фильтра данные возвращаются в URL, подскажите как их оттуда использовать

Tags: javascript, url

...tasks?service=&city=4&price=&status=&search=&specialist=&owner=&petsString=2&pets%5B0%5D=2&sizes%5B0%5D=1&sizes%5B1%5D=2

Вот пример части Url

Comment: Возвращаются куда? В PHP, например, вы можете их получить в массиве $_GET Но к чему здесь JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Берем текущий URL
const url = new URL(window.location.href);

//Обращаемся к нужному параметру
let city   = url.searchParams.get("сity");
```